# Flutter: Can't click listview item on integration test

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I have an app with a listview feature with provider pattern, and it has 5 items of data. Here is my snippet code

```
    ListView.builder(
      key: Key("listview_portfolio"),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          _itemListPortofolio(data.items[index], context),
      itemCount: data.items.length,
    )
```

...

```
    Widget _itemListPortofolio(Portfolio portfolio, BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        key: ValueKey("item_list_portfolio"),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
        child: InkWell(
```

When I run this code, it doesn't throw an error, but when I do the integration test, it throws an error when trying to click the item listview

> 'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 802 pos 14: '_pendingExceptionDetails != null': A test
> overrode FlutterError.onError but either failed to return it to its original state, or had unexpected additional errors that it could
> not handle. Typically, this is caused by using expect() before restoring FlutterError.onError.
> flutter:   dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart 51:61       _AssertionError._doThrowNew

here's my integration test class

```
    Future<void> tapPortfolioItem({bool scrollUp = false}) async {
        await _tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 5));
        final Widget itemPortfolio =
            find.byKey(ValueKey("item_list_portfolio")).evaluate().last.widget;

        await _tester.tap(find.byWidget(itemPortfolio));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below:

```
final Finder instance = find.byKey(ValueKey("item_list_portifolio"));
final _itemListPortofolio test = _tester.widget(instance);
await _tester.tap(instance);
expect(anything, findsOneWidget);
expect(test.color, Colors.red);
```

see also other  way to use `pumpAndSeatle()` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html).